# Readme appearance instead of index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, github, github-pages, readme

I'm new at this: is there any way to let github build a page with the `index.html` file that is placed in a folder instead of `readme`?

I've been successfully building a lot of pages with that the index file isn't in a folder. But when it comes to websites that include Angular or node.js, the index file has to be in a folder so when github builds a page, the `readme` file appears instead of the actual site.

Is there a solution?

1. https://github.com/JanviaveTharwat/weather-app

That's one of the websites built with node.js. This is what appears to me after building page

https://janviavetharwat.github.io/weather-app/

2. https://github.com/JanviaveTharwat/angular-store-

Here is the second website with Angular. This is what happened:

https://janviavetharwat.github.io/angular-store-/

Can you help me ?

Comment: Is this a screening test for a job interview?

Comment: No ,I'm trying to build my portfolio  with every thing I've done

Comment: These 2 projects are for a 2 courses that ive took

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide for deploying Angular applications to GitHub Pages from the official Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages) and the GitHub Pages documentation for the setup on GitHub itself [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch).

These are the steps as of **Dec 23 2022**:

Assuming your project already has an GitHub repository, follow these steps:

1. Create and checkout a git branch named `gh-pages`:

```bash
git checkout -b gh-pages
```

2. Build your project with the following command and flags:

```bash
ng build --output-path docs --base-href /<your-project-name>/
```

3. When the build is finished, make a copy of the `docs/index.html` file and name it `docs/404.html`
4. Commit your changes and push them - make sure that the `docs` directory is included
5. On the project GitHub repository, go to `Settings`
6. In the `Code and automation` section of the sidebar, click on `Pages`
7. Under `Build and deployment`, under `Source` select `Deploy from a branch`
8. Under `Build and deployment`, under `Branch` and select your `gh-pages` branch
9. Use the drop-down to the right of the branch drop-down to select the `docs` folder
10. Click `Save`. Your application should now be deployed and accessible under `https://<user_name>.github.io/<project_name>`